# Antifreeze problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Car manufacturer recommends that a mixture of 65% antifreeze be used.

How much 50% antifreeze solution should be drained from a 4 gal tank and replaced with pure antifreeze to produce a 65% antifreeze mixture?

I have $$0.50\cdot(4-x)+1.00\cdot x=0.65\cdot4$$

Is this right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Yes. Absolutely right..............

Comment: You can also leave the percentages, $50\cdot(4-x)+100\cdot x=65\cdot4$.